# Dimension reduction using combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am working on reducing the dimension of a huge dataset and I would like your help to understand the dimension reduction that I have achieved. I think that the calculation should be based on some combinatorics but I'm not sure how.

Take the integers $T,K$. Consider the vector $(L_1,..., L_T)$
where each $t$-th element is an integer between $1$ and $K$. For example, for $T=3, K=4$, we can have $(L_1,L_2, L_3)\equiv (1,1,4)$.

Consider all possible ways of disposing the integers $\{0,1\}$ in a row vector of size $1\times T$, where repetitions are allowed and the order matters. Note that we can construct $2^T$ row vectors, each generically denoted by $(R_1,..., R_T)$. For example, for $T=2$, the vectors are $(1,1),(1,0),(0,1),(0,0)$.

Now, I want to partition these row vectors in groups such that the row vectors in each group are characterised by the same:
$$
\sum_{\tau=1}^T R_\tau *   1\{L_\tau=1\}, \sum_{\tau=1}^T R_\tau *   1\{L_\tau=2\}, \dots, \sum_{\tau=1}^T R_\tau *   1\{L_\tau=K\}
$$
where $1\{\dots\}$ denotes the indicator function taking value $1$ if the condition inside is satisfied and zero otherwise.

For example, given $(L_1,L_2,L_3)=(1,1,4)$, then $(R_1, R_2, R_3)=(1,0,0)$ and $(R_1, R_2,R_3)=(0,1,0)$ will belong to the same group.

**Question:** how many such groups will I create for each given $(L_1,\dots, L_T)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $i\in \{1,\dots,K\}$, let $n_i$ be the number of occurences of $i$ in $(L_1,\dots,L_T)$. The number of different groups is
$$
(n_1+1)(n_2+1)\cdots(n_K+1)
$$
This is because the number of places where a $1$ in $(R_1,\dots,R_T)$ overlaps with a particular symbol $i$ in $(L_1,\dots,L_T)$ can be anywhere between $0$ and $n_i$, for a total of $(n_i+1)$ choices. The number of overlaps can be chosen independently for each symbol.